# Debugging kotlin jars

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

Is there a way to step into a function in an imported jar in kotlin?

Context: a project makes use of a number of jar files, when instantiating an imported object and calling one of its methods the debugger is unable to go the implementation of said method (the object is an instance of a class implementing one or more interfaces).

In intellij idea (2023, eap), Ctrl + left click goes to the (kotlin) interface and not the implementation. When clicking decompile class to java, java code is produced but it's useless in that it cannot be stepped into at runtime.

The project from which the jar was built is available; however the branch/commit from which it was generated is not (there are several branches and a lot of derelict code).

Serialization and reflection come to mind but is there a more convenient way?

Comment: Maybe you could try to release a new jar from that project with the source available for publishing and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that Kotlin compiles down to byte code that cannot often be turned back into either Java or Kotlin.

Despite not having the source, the debugger will still step through the code, just you may not have a valid source.  Often I find that you can still deduce what the code is doing from the method names (which will be available in the Stack) and the arguments available and a copy of the source at earlier/later point given that code changes are often small.

Another idea: given

> The project from which the jar was built is available

unzip the jar file and you'll find all the .class files will have nearly the same datetime, from the point the artefact was made.  Could you use *this* to find the closest commit in the project source code control and wind the HEAD of the project back to the point that may represent the point at which the jar file was produced?  (This can get tricky a feature branch was merged into master).